# Move content from a CSV with a different name to CSV

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

with the following Batch Code could I move content from csv to csv:

```
set "Quelle=C:\Users\Administrator\.barcode\log\log.csv"
set "Ziel=C:\Users\Administrator\barcode\scripts\import.csv"
for %%i in ("%Quelle%") do type "%%i">>"%Ziel%" & echo.>>"%Ziel%"
```

But the file-name could ne different. With *.csv it ist not working. Could anyone help me?

Comment: If I understood right, even a simple `copy` would work: `copy "C:\Users\Administrator\.barcode\log\*.csv" "C:\Users\Administrator\barcode\scripts\"`

Comment: That‘s an Idea, but the *.csv have the following content: 1;Test; - after the batch run the target file have the content: 1;Test; - on the Second run the *.csv have the content: 2;Test123; and the Target file 1;Test;2;Test123; and so on.

Comment: Try `>> "%Ziel%" rem/` (ensures `%Ziel%` exists), then `copy "%Ziel%"+"%Quelle%" "%ZIEL%" /B` (appends `%Quelle%` to `%Ziel%`). Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56789970) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59860109)...